# How do I get the column name (or number) of a multi series zoo object when I apply by row?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have a zoo object of 12 sets of monthly returns on stock tickers. I want to get the symbol, which is the name of the series, or at least the column, of each month's best performing stock. I've been trying to do this with applying the max function, by row. How do I get the column name?

```
#Apply 'max' function across each row. I need to get the col number out of this.
apply(tsPctChgs, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `apply` converts to matrix, I would use `rollapply` with `width=1`:

```
require("zoo")
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(runif(50), ncol=5)
mz <- setNames(zoo(m, seq(nrow(m))), paste0("Series",seq(ncol(m))))
rollapply(mz, 1, function(r) colnames(mz)[which.max(r)], by.column=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks. Big help. I hope I'm not missing a key point of functionality by streamlining, but it looks like all I needed was:rollapply(mz, 1, function(r) colnames(mz)[which.max(r)], by.column=FALSE)

Comment: @StatsViaCsh Yes, @Joushua was creating a reproducible example in the first 4 lines. Assuming you already have a **zoo** object set up as you want, you can go straight to line 5 and replace `mz` with your object name. Note it would be nicer code if it was `rollapply(mz, 1, function(r, z) colnames(z)[which.max(r)], by.column=FALSE, z = mz)` because we should pass in everything a function needs to work - but that is splitting hairs.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work (possible add here "as nicely") with ties - as explained in my Answer - if you want the series names of all series taking the maximum. `rollapply(mz2, 1, function(r, z) colnames(z)[which(r == max(r))], by.column=FALSE, z = mz2)` handles the ties, but replicates the series names if there is only one maximum.

Answer (score 4):

The usual answer would be via `which.max()` however, do note that this will return only the first of the maximums if there are two or more observations taking the maximum value.

An alternative is `which(x == max(x))`, which would return all value taking the maximum in the result of a tie.

You can then use the index returned to select the series maximum. Handling `NA`s is covered below to try to keep the initial discussion simple.

```
require("zoo")
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(runif(50), ncol = 5)
colnames(m) <- paste0("Series", seq_len(ncol(m)))
ind <- seq_len(nrow(m))

mz <- zoo(m, order.by = ind)

> apply(mz, 1, which.max)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 3  5  5  1  4  1  1  2  3  2

> apply(mz, 1, function(x) which(x == max(x)))
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 3  5  5  1  4  1  1  2  3  2
```

So use that to select the series name

```
i1 <- apply(mz, 1, function(x) which(x == max(x)))
colnames(mz)[i1]

> i1 <- apply(mz, 1, function(x) which(x == max(x)))
> colnames(mz)[i1]
 [1] "Series3" "Series5" "Series5" "Series1" "Series4" "Series1" "Series1"
 [8] "Series2" "Series3" "Series2"
```

#### Handling tied maximums

To illustrate the different behaviour, copy the maximum from month 1 (series 3) into series 1

```
mz2 <- mz ## copy
mz2[1,1] <- mz[1,3]
mz2[1,]

> mz2[1,]

1 0.9347052 0.2059746 0.9347052 0.4820801 0.8209463
```

Now try the two approaches again

```
> apply(mz2, 1, which.max)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  5  5  1  4  1  1  2  3  2 
> apply(mz2, 1, function(x) which(x == max(x)))
$`1`
Series1 Series3 
      1       3
.... ## truncated output ###
```

Notice how `which.max` only returns the maximum in series 1.

To use this approach to select the series name, you need to apply something to the list returned by `apply()`, e.g.

```
i2 <- apply(mz2, 1, function(x) which(x == max(x)))
lapply(i2, function (i, zobj) colnames(zobj)[i], zobj = mz2)

$`1`
[1] "Series1" "Series3"

$`2`
[1] "Series5"

$`3`
[1] "Series5"

$`4`
[1] "Series1"

$`5`
[1] "Series4"

$`6`
[1] "Series1"

$`7`
[1] "Series1"

$`8`
[1] "Series2"

$`9`
[1] "Series3"

$`10`
[1] "Series2"
```

#### Handling `NA`s

As you have potential for `NA`s, I would do the following:

```
apply(mz, 1, which.max, na.rm = TRUE) ## as you did already
apply(mz, 1, function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
               if(na.rm) {
                 x <- x[!is.na(x)]
               }
               which(x == max(x))
             })
```